# TPE 1105 for BulkRequestTransmissionStatus A2A IRS

Tags: java, xml, http, soap, irs

Now that I was finally able to pass the 1105 and 1122 respectively for the bulk transmission service, I am back up against the 1105 for the status request. I've re-used code for signing and generating my http request, so not much there should have issue. Below is my packet sent with formatting and values redacted.

```
            POST /core/ws/lite/a2a/test/here/there HTTP/1.1
            Content-Encoding: gzip
            Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
            Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<root_part>"; boundary="--=_part_60cb735e-c276-4405-834a-50d9b589636e"; start-info="text/xml"
            SOAPAction: "RequestSubmissionStatusDetail"
            MIME-Version: 1.0
            Host: la.www4.irs.gov
            Connection: Keep-Alive
            Expect: 100-Continue
            Content-Length: 3177


            ----=_part_60cb735e-c276-4405-834a-50d9b589636e
            Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"
            Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
            Content-Id: <root_part>

            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
            <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:irstransmitterstatusrequest" xmlns:urn1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:ty18" xmlns:urn2="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:urn3="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acasecurityheader">
                <env:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-f2b7b3e293a642c58f7e48656be85b30">
                            <ds:SignedInfo>
                                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#WithComments"/>
                                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                                <ds:Reference URI="#TS-b4302e87b74441b6bf13eeae3c13f124">
                                    <ds:Transforms>
                                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                            <ds:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsse wsa env urn urn1 urn2 urn3"/>
                                        </ds:Transform>
                                    </ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                    <ds:DigestValue>[DIGEST VALUE]</ds:DigestValue>
                                </ds:Reference>
                                <ds:Reference URI="#id-c6d0bbd68f5e40a493ed5462878a4fde">
                                    <ds:Transforms>
                                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                            <ds:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsa env urn1 urn2"/>
                                        </ds:Transform>
                                    </ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                    <ds:DigestValue>[DIGEST VALUE]</ds:DigestValue>
                                </ds:Reference>
                                <ds:Reference URI="#id-f57af9d1ed1640af89227d5878799924">
                                    <ds:Transforms>
                                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                            <ds:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="env urn urn1 urn2 urn3"/>
                                        </ds:Transform>
                                    </ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                    <ds:DigestValue>[DIGEST VALUE]</ds:DigestValue>
                                </ds:Reference>
                            </ds:SignedInfo>
                            <ds:SignatureValue>[SIGNATURE VALUE]</ds:SignatureValue>
                            <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-f2b7b3e293a642c58f7e48656be85b30">
                                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-f2b7b3e293a642c58f7e48656be85b30">
                                    <wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">[CERT VALUE]</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
                                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                            </ds:KeyInfo>
                        </ds:Signature>
                        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-b4302e87b74441b6bf13eeae3c13f124">
                            <wsu:Created>2019-03-20T21:28:01.017Z</wsu:Created>
                            <wsu:Expires>2019-03-20T21:38:01.017Z</wsu:Expires>
                        </wsu:Timestamp>
                    </wsse:Security>
                    <urn:ACABusinessHeader xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-c6d0bbd68f5e40a493ed5462878a4fde">
                        <urn1:UniqueTransmissionId>[UTID]</urn1:UniqueTransmissionId>
                        <urn2:Timestamp>2019-03-20T20:59:49Z</urn2:Timestamp>
                    </urn:ACABusinessHeader>
                    <urn3:ACASecurityHeader>
                        <urn2:UserId>[ASID]</urn2:UserId>
                    </urn3:ACASecurityHeader>
                    <wsa:Action>RequestSubmissionStatusDetail</wsa:Action>
                </env:Header>
                <env:Body>
                    <urn:ACABulkRequestTransmitterStatusDetailRequest xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" version="1.0" wsu:Id="id-f57af9d1ed1640af89227d5878799924">
                        <urn1:ACABulkReqTrnsmtStsReqGrpDtl>
                            <urn2:ReceiptId>[RECEIPT]</urn2:ReceiptId>
                        </urn1:ACABulkReqTrnsmtStsReqGrpDtl>
                    </urn:ACABulkRequestTransmitterStatusDetailRequest>
                </env:Body>
            </env:Envelope>
            ----=_part_60cb735e-c276-4405-834a-50d9b589636e--
```

I'm not certain where to begin to troubleshoot this one as the documentation is more scant on the status request than it was on the actual transmission itself. I know my signature and elements are valid, although I am uncertain about the inclusive namespaces. If you have used the publication 5258 you will know the 2 given examples for the transmission service showed 2 different variations, one being from the previous year. The status request only has a single example, and it is from last year. I am certain my other necessary values are correct, the UserId field, and Unique Transmission Id, although redacted here. Any help here is appreciated.

EDIT-- I know the URL is wrong, that's just an internal endpoint to capture the traffic outside of SSL. Also, I have tried 8bit instead of binary, as that was how the original transmission service is setup from our end.

Answer (score 2):

I've compared what you've posted with what I am sending over and I don't see too much of a difference in the XML itself, I don't remember if the IRS is picky about indention on this request or not but I currently have no indenting in the SOAP I'm sending.

I'm not sending it using any MTOM boundaries, I'm simply reading the SOAP XML into a gzip request stream and throwing that out to the WSDL URL.

Below is a sample of what I've sent when I compared yours (taken and formatted from a raw output from Fiddler, it had no previous formatting)

```
POST [URL] HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: RequestSubmissionStatusDetail
Host: la.www4.irs.gov
Content-Length: 6194
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:oas1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:urn="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:irstransmitterstatusrequest" 
    xmlns:urn1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:ty18" 
    xmlns:urn2="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" 
    xmlns:urn3="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acasecurityheader">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <Signature Id="SIG-D2FB25526C8348AD95E612881F40EB95" 
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#WithComments" />
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                    <Reference URI="#TS-200BDCDA5B0C4C468DFEB0581AA15570">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse wsa oas1 soapenv urn urn1 urn2 urn3" 
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                            </Transform>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                        <DigestValue>[VALUE]</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#id-204B33EDA74348ACABB3B791BEBF97F2">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsa oas1 soapenv urn1 urn2 urn3" 
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                            </Transform>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                        <DigestValue>[VALUE]</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#id-D11B31E69B5B412EBA078A7C03C68D0D">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="oas1 soapenv urn1 urn2 urn3" 
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                            </Transform>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                        <DigestValue>[VALUE]</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>[VALUE]</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo Id="KI-A5CB548510AE48DF96C37ADF55E71AE6">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-2B2450C3AC8B46C990E1328C2B53473B">
                        <wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">[VALUE]</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-200BDCDA5B0C4C468DFEB0581AA15570">
                <wsu:Created>2019-03-22T18:11:32.991Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2019-03-22T18:21:32.991Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
        <urn:ACABusinessHeader wsu:Id="id-204B33EDA74348ACABB3B791BEBF97F2" 
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <urn1:UniqueTransmissionId>[VALUE]</urn1:UniqueTransmissionId>
            <urn2:Timestamp>2019-03-22T18:11:32Z</urn2:Timestamp>
        </urn:ACABusinessHeader>
        <urn3:ACASecurityHeader>
            <urn2:UserId>[VALUE]</urn2:UserId>
        </urn3:ACASecurityHeader>
        <wsa:Action>RequestSubmissionStatusDetail</wsa:Action>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:ACABulkRequestTransmitterStatusDetailRequest version="1.0" wsu:Id="id-D11B31E69B5B412EBA078A7C03C68D0D" 
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <urn1:ACABulkReqTrnsmtStsReqGrpDtl>
                <urn2:ReceiptId>1094C-19-XXXXXXXX</urn2:ReceiptId>
            </urn1:ACABulkReqTrnsmtStsReqGrpDtl>
        </urn:ACABulkRequestTransmitterStatusDetailRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Gonna go ahead and say that's the answer. Immediately after changing to the non-multipart, or the way you show above, i progressed to the 1122 which I'm not as afraid of as I was ;) . Thanks to both Das and Russ for the help. Maybe we should get together and re-write the docs for them next year haha.

Answer (score 1):

I will agree with what Das said, I don't believe formatting of the soap request matters.  My request looks similar or the same as Das'.

When I compared yours to one of mine that I have previously sent I see the following:

- You are using a `ds` prefix (defined in the `Signature` element), where myself and Das are not;
- Das and I are both using a `xmlns:oasi` namepsace in the `Envelope` element where this is omitted in yours.
- The formatting/order of some of the attributes is different, but I don't think this is actually a problem.

I seem to recall attempting to use the `ds` prefix in my transmissions initially, and the transmissions not working.  However, I don't remember if this was specific to only the Status Transmission or if it also occurred in the Submission as well.

Instead of explictly defining the namespace prefix of the `Signature` element, I am using `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"` for it -- you have this as `xmlns:ds`.

Comment: Russ is that an 'i' as in 'eye' or a 1 'one', at the end of oas for that prefix? Also I doubt that should matter but with the A2A endpoints I take nothing for granted ha. I actually have the `ds` prefix on my submission, not sure if it will affect the status submission or not as of yet. It is only a single line to remove or add that prefix so I've been testing all changes both ways, thanks for the suggestion. EDIT -- that's an L. I'm a bit blind. Same point as before, it really should not matter but I'll try anything at this point!

Comment: It is an i as in "eye".